# Placeholder is not seen in input

Tags: placeholder

Here is the part of my code in which I have problems. I can't understand why the Placeholders are not seen. It's not the problem of the browser (I open another HTML here and placeholders work). Please, hint what can be wrong.

```html
<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" class="contacts__form">
            <input name="Имя" type="text" placeholder="Имя*" data-validate-field="name"
              class="contacts__form-input form-name" autocomplete="off" id="name">
            <input name="tel" type="tel" class="contacts__form-input form-phone" placeholder="Телефон*"
              data-validate-field="tel" data-validate-rules="phone" autocomplete="off" id="tel">
            <button class="btn-reset contacts__form-btn" id="submit-btn">Заказать обратный звонок</button>
          </form>
```

Head:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/flavicon.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/choices.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/accordion.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/simplebar@latest/dist/simplebar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/choices.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="js/painters-buttons.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/just-validate@latest/dist/just-validate.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/inputmask.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/ymaps.js"></script>
```

scripts at the end of the body:

```js
<script src="js/focus-visible.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/slider.js"></script>
  <script src="js/select.js"></script>
  <script src="js/accordion.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/accordion.js"></script>
  <script src="js/validation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/validation-rules.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```css
.contacts__form-input {
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.form-name, .form-phone {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: var(--dusty-gray-color);
}

.contacts__form-btn {
  margin-right: 69px;
  padding: 12.5px 35px;
  padding-right: 36px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: var(--amethyst-color);
  border: 2px solid var(--amethyst-color);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

I tried to change font-family, changed var to normal bright color, and even inserted the code from another HTML, where the placeholders are seen. Nothing works.

Comment: None of us here knows, what all those local stylesheets and scripts you are embedding there, actually contain. (Especially, since you did not even tag or mention any specific frameworks you might be using.) If you want our help with issues like this, then you need to present a proper [mre] of the issue.

Comment: I tried switching off all the libraries but placeholders didn't appear.... So it's not because of this I presume

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be simple. I have already used placeholder for the a search input above in the code. This link helped [Multiple styles for input placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521929/multiple-styles-for-input-placeholder-text)
All is solved.